# What is the correct way to retopologize?

Tags: retopology

I made my first full sculpture, but when i start manually retopologizing as shown in tutorials my plane doesnt seem to snap on the surface of the sculpture but inside it, does this matter? can i get some advice?. i dont want to waste hours to see it wasnt meant to be done this way :/ [image: the plane inside]

Comment: You could give a Shrinkwrap modifier to your object with an offset that will make it shift a bit from the surface

Comment: I believe the vertices snap to the surface so the faces will always be slightly inside.  I would take moon's advice.

Comment: Yes! You were right, the vertices will always be a little inside the mesh, and yes I applied shrinkwrap at the end and in took the shape very well, thanks